# Referencing a variable from another class

Tags: python, tkinter

- I edited my code from what I original posted. I used an example that was oversimplified. I am adding to the dictionary, 'my dict' in the CalcVar class and want to display the updated value on the 'Display Var'page.

I have provided my code below. There is no error, but it is not performing how I would like. In the 'Display Var' class I am showing the output for myvar. I want it to show two labels, one which says 'dict 1 ' and another one that says 'dict 2'. Right now it just pulls the original value of 'dict 1'. The first step for the program is to go to the Calc Var page and I add 'dict 2' to mydict. From there I want to go to the 'Display Var' page and display the edited dictionary so that it shows are 'dict 1 ' and 'dict 2', but it only will show as 'dict 1'. How do I make it show as 'dict 1 ' and 'dict 2?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT= ("Times New Roman", 22)


class MyApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        global mydict
        mydict = {'dict1' : {"a b c" : 123}} # set its value


        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (CalcVar, DisplayVar):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(CalcVar)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class CalcVar(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)


        def addvar():
            global mydict
            #myvar.set(myvar.get()+" c") # when add the value.
            dict2 = {'d e f' : 456}
            mydict['dict 2'] = dict2
            print(mydict)



        label = tk.Label(self, text="Calculation Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)



        button = tk.Button(self, text="Display Results",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DisplayVar))
        button.pack()


        calcbutton = tk.Button(self, text="AddVar",
                            command=addvar)
        calcbutton.pack()



class DisplayVar(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global mydict

        for x, y in mydict.items():
            label = tk.Label(self, text=x, font=LARGE_FONT) 
            label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Calculation Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(CalcVar))
        button1.pack()
```

Comment: You only want it show `dict1` and `dict2`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my example has gotten messy. I would like to create two labels on the 'DisplayVar' tab. One that says "dict1" and another Label that says "dict2". Effectively eventually, I would like a variable number of dictionaries in 'mydict' and the 'DisplayVar' page would create a label with the name of each dictionary. I am getting errors when I try to do that with a string variable.

Comment: Your code is a little hard to read.You could make it "two label" in visual.Use `\n` to join the keys in the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't "Referencing a variable from another class".When your run it in the first time,the text is "a,b".Even though you call `addvar()` next time,the text in label won't be changed.You could use a `textvariable` instead of `text` in the `Label` widget.

Followed by your code:

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class MyApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        global myvar # global
        myvar = tk.StringVar() # create a StringVar and assign it myvar
        myvar.set("a b") # set its value

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (CalcVar, DisplayVar):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(CalcVar)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class CalcVar(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        def addvar():
            global myvar
            myvar.set(myvar.get()+" c") # when add the value.
            print(myvar.get())

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Calculation Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Display Results",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DisplayVar))
        button.pack()

        calcbutton = tk.Button(self, text="AddVar",
                            command=addvar)
        calcbutton.pack()

class DisplayVar(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global myvar

        label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=myvar, font=LARGE_FONT) # bind a textvariable not text
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Calculation Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(CalcVar))
        button1.pack()

app = MyApp()
app.geometry('750x500')

app.mainloop()
```

---

Edit:The principle is the same even if you want to use a dict.The easiest way is use `textvaribale`.But if you want to show the string in the dict.Just use `myvar.set(xx)` to set it.

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class MyApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        global myvar,mydict # global
        mydict = {'dict 1' : {"a b c" : 123}}
        myvar = tk.StringVar() # create a StringVar and assign it myvar
        myvar.set(" ".join(i for i in mydict)) # set "dict 1" string

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (CalcVar, DisplayVar):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(CalcVar)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class CalcVar(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        def addvar():
            global myvar,mydict
            dict2 = {'d e f' : 456}
            mydict['dict 2'] = dict2 # add it to your dict
            myvar.set(" ".join(i for i in mydict)) # also set the vale and show it.
            print(myvar.get())

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Calculation Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Display Results",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DisplayVar))
        button.pack()

        calcbutton = tk.Button(self, text="AddVar",
                            command=addvar)
        calcbutton.pack()

class DisplayVar(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global myvar

        label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=myvar, font=LARGE_FONT) # bind a textvariable not text
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Calculation Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(CalcVar))
        button1.pack()

app = MyApp()
app.geometry('750x500')

app.mainloop()
```

---

I strongly recommend you just use `\n` to join them(That's very easy and fast),if you really want to create two label widgets.This is code(maybe it is not the best way):

```
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class MyApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        global mydict # global
        mydict = {'dict 1' : {"a b c" : 123}}

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (CalcVar, DisplayVar):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(CalcVar)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class CalcVar(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        def addvar(p,c):
            global mydict
            for i in p.winfo_children()[0].winfo_children(): # delete all the widget in the displayVar
                i.pack_forget()
            mydict['dict 2']={'d e f':456}
            for i in mydict: # then pack them in it.
                tk.Label(p.winfo_children()[0],text=i).pack(pady=10,padx=10)
            button1 = tk.Button(p.winfo_children()[0], text="Back to Calculation Page",
                                command=lambda: c.show_frame(CalcVar))
            button1.pack()

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Calculation Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Display Results",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DisplayVar))
        button.pack()

        calcbutton = tk.Button(self, text="AddVar",
                            command=lambda :addvar(parent,controller))
        calcbutton.pack()

class DisplayVar(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global mydict

        for i in mydict:
            print(i)
            tk.Label(self, text=i).pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Calculation Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(CalcVar))
        button1.pack()

app = MyApp()
app.geometry('750x500')

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. What if myvar was a dictionary instead of a string?

Comment: I edited my original code to show as a dictionary. I tried to follow your suggestion, but I still am not getting the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies. Very helpful and much appreciated!